# VBA: How to delete filtered rows in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have an Excel table that contains some data. By using next vba code I'm trying to filter only blank cells in some fields and delete these rows

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lines).AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
        "="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lines).AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        "="
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lines).AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
        "="
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.Count - 1).rows.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
```

It works only if I have blank cells in this columns. 
But I faced with a problem, when I do not have blank cells, and by using above code all my range is removing from the sheet. How to avoid this issue? Should I change my filter condition or something else?

Comment: Hey, can you help me define what is the "lines" you mention in your code

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use SpecialCells to delete only the rows that are visible after autofiltering:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lines).SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

If you have a header row in your range that you don't want to delete, add an offset to the range to exclude it:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$" & lines).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Method explained on [this page](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/row-delete-criteria.htm) combines the filtering and offsetting and deleting, which makes reading code easier.
    `With rRange 'Filter, offset(to exclude headers) and delete visible rows
      .AutoFilter Field:=lCol, Criteria1:=strCriteria
      .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With`

Comment: just precede the delete line with a try-catch block as it throws an error if you try to delete an empty selection 

: On Error Resume Next

Comment: Hi just wondering how can I modify the above line to delete hidden rows after filter ?

Comment: What is `lines`? is it a vba **row** variable or does the programmer define it?

Answer (score 21):

As an alternative to using UsedRange or providing an explicit range address, the AutoFilter.Range property can also specify the affected range.

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1,0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete(xlShiftUp)
```

As used here, Offset causes the first row after the AutoFilter range to also be deleted. In order to avoid that, I would try using .Resize() after .Offset().

Comment: Good solution, but works only with autofiltered views, not with data marked up as table... It would be just perfect, if it would do.