# Is there a way to prompt the user of the macro to input their own date range?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a beginner at using macros. I would like to be able to input my own date range for the analysis that follows. For example May 1st 2019 to June 30th 2019. This is what I have for this case, however I would like that to be able to vary so therefore would need some sort of prompt to the user. I would also need the data that isn't within that time range to be deleted from the worksheet. What i have im not sure how that would work. Thank you~

```
Sub DateQuery()
' DateQuery Macro
  ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_main_drawings").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, _
        Criteria1:=">=5/1/2019", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=6/30/2019"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Totally possible. You can declare two variables to store the dates, and then use `InputBox()` to get user input:

```
Sub DateQuery()
' DateQuery Macro
    'Define two variables to hold your dates
    Dim fromDate As String
    Dim toDate As String

    'Ask the user for the dates
    fromDate = InputBox("Please enter the start date using date format mm/dd/yyyy", "Start Date")
    toDate = InputBox("Please enter the end date using date format mm/dd/yyyy", "End Date")

    'Use your variables by concatenating them into your existing code
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_main_drawings").Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & fromDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & toDate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. ~ I will still need to delete the rest of the data that was not part of the desired time period. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: I would reverse that filter so the ones you want to delete are visible then use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194394/vba-how-to-delete-filtered-rows-in-excel) to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

@JNevill hit the nail on the head. However, in preparation for addressing your second goal to remove data not in the given time range, I would suggest either A) declaration of `fromDate` and `toDate` as `Date` type, or B) conversion of `fromDate` and `toDate` to `Date` via `Format()`.

See `Format()` documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1008925)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue).