# Run Time Error 1004 (Delete Method of Range Object failed) by deleting filtered rows

Tags: vba, runtime-error, delete-row, autofilter

I want to filter my Excel table by two criterias and delete the filtered rows. I wrote the following code:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1").ListObjects("coordinates").Range 
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=longitude_arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=latitude_arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

The filtering works fine, but the delete part gets me a runtime error 1004: Delete Method of Range Object failed.
I don't see the problem, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the error is thrown because you try to delete rows from a table, but you have also one row that is not part of the table: The `Offset(1, 0)` will add the first row *after* the table to the rows to be deleted.

Try the following code - it will remove this extra row before deletion. Also, I added a check if anything is to be deleted, if not, skip the delete-command (else you would get a runtime error)

```
Dim sourceRange As Range
Set sourceRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1").ListObjects("coordinates").Range
With sourceRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=longitude_arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=latitude_arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues        Dim filterRange As Range
    Set filterRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
    Dim deleteRange as Range
    Set deleteRange = Intersect(filterRange, sourceRange)
    if not deleteRange is Nothing then deleteRange.Delete
End With
```

**Update** Obviously I made a mistake when copying my test code by keeping my Autofilter-command, replaced it with the one from the quesion.

Playing around revealed some details:
**o** The `Delete` will also fail because of the `EntireRow`.
**o** I was not aware that there is a `DataBodyRange`-Object for a ListObject, thats makes it much easier.
**o** I also forgot that  `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` throws a runtime error rather than returning `Nothing`, so you need to enclose this with `On Error`.
**o** If you want to get rid of the question if you want to delete the entire row, use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

I now end up with

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=longitude_arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=latitude_arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Dim filterRange As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set filterRange = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Not filterRange Is Nothing Then filterRange.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End With
```

Comment: The Offset was not meant to remove the first row after the table, but it should prevent that the header is deleted.
I got my code here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194394/vba-how-to-delete-filtered-rows-in-excel) and misinterpreted it.

Comment: I corrected it like this: 
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1").ListObjects("coordinates").DataBodyRange .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=longitude_arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=latitude_arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues On Error Resume Next .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete On Error GoTo 0 End With 
This works if I have only one row as result of the filter, but I get the same error as before if I have more resulting rows.