# "Delete method of range class failed" when trying to delete filtered rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I want to filter the table, then delete the rows that are visible, leaving only the rows that were not filtered in an essentially "new" table.

```vb
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Score")

    Set TestTable = ws.ListObjects("Score")
    With ws
        .Range(TestTable & "[Correct/Incorrect]").AutoFilter 6, "Correct"
        .Range(TestTable & "[Correct/Incorrect]").Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Relevant:  [How to delete filtered rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194394/vba-how-to-delete-filtered-rows-in-excel)

Comment: I followed the instructions on this page and did not have any different results.  Still showing the same error on the same line.

Comment: What error on what line? Is deleting the rows the only problem, or is there something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```vb
Sub deleteFilterdRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Score")

Dim lo as ListObject
Set lo = ws.ListObjects("Score")

lo.DataBodyRange.AutoFilter field:=lo.ListColumns("Correct/Incorrect").Index, Criteria1:="Correct"

Dim rgFiltered As Range
On Error Resume Next    'if nothing was found/filtered
With lo.Range
   Set rgFiltered = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End With
On Error GoTo 0

lo.AutoFilter.ShowAllData 'remove filter otherwise deletion is not possible

If Not rgFiltered Is Nothing Then
    rgFiltered.Delete
End If


End Sub
```

First of all: you set the autofilter in a wrong way:
`.Range(TestTable & "[Correct/Incorrect]")` won't work as you are combining the listobject with a string.

Second you need to apply the visible rows to an extra range and undo the filter. Within a filtered listobject you can't delete rows (same in frontend).

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Excel Table Rows (ListObject)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteListObjectRows()
        
    ' Define constants.
    Const wsName As String = "Score"
    Const tblName As String = "Score"
    Const lcName As String = "Correct/Incorrect"
    Const Criteria As String = "Correct"
        
    ' Reference the workbook, worksheet and table.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(tblName)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim vrg As Range
    
    With tbl
        
        ' Check if the autofilter arrows are turned on.
        If .ShowAutoFilter Then ' autofilter arrows are turned on
            ' Clear any table filters.
            If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        Else ' autofilter arrows are turned off
            .ShowAutoFilter = True ' turn on the autofilter arrows
        End If
        
        ' Reference the criteria list column ('lc').
        Dim lc As ListColumn: Set lc = .ListColumns(lcName)
        ' Filter the table range.
        .Range.AutoFilter lc.Index, Criteria
        
        ' Attempt to reference the visible range ('vrg').
        On Error Resume Next
            Set vrg = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        ' Clear the filter.
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    
    End With
    
    ' Validate and delete the visible range.
    If Not vrg Is Nothing Then vrg.Delete xlShiftUp

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    If Not vrg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Table criteria rows deleted.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No table criteria rows found.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub
```