# How to delete the filtered rows by the fastest method?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, autofilter

I have a dataset of 30k rows and 15 column.
I have set autofilter on column "`O`" to select the cells contains string "`x`" and delete all these rows.
the code takes a lot of time to finish (about 14 seconds) on a very power PC.
Is my code formulated well or there is a faster method to delete these filtered rows?
In advance, grateful for any helpful comments and answers.

```
Sub Macro1()

   Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastR As Long, lastC As Long
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                      'Last Row on column 1
     lastC = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column             'Last Column on Row 1
     
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lastR, lastC))

    ws.Rows("1:1").AutoFilter
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="x"
    
    Intersect(ws.Cells, rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Delete
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Deleting rows is always quicker if those rows are contiguous, so sort the table appropriately first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA: How to delete filtered rows in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194394/vba-how-to-delete-filtered-rows-in-excel)

Comment: @braX , the provided answer on your comment is the same as my code on question, I also tried ,but the same issue.

Comment: @Jos Woolley , I tried your suggestion. It finished in 4.61 seconds after it was 14 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Joe said, sorting the data may help. I'd like to add that turning `ScreenUpdating` and automatic calculation off may significantly reduce the execution time (don't forget to turn them on at the end of the code). Also, using arrays is much-much faster than working with worksheets directly. Though, attention must be paid whether the data are static (i.e., don't depend on the rest of the data that might be changed).

I wrote a simple piece of code to test how faster (or slower) will it be to work with arrays.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim n_rows As Long
Dim n_cols As Integer
Dim r_pointer As Long
Dim arr_in() As Variant
Dim arr_out() As Variant
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Integer

Const idx_init As Integer = 1
Const c_target As Integer = 15
Const s_cmp As String = "x"

n_rows = 30000
n_cols = 15

Set sh = Sheet1
Set rng = sh.Range("A1").Resize(n_rows, n_cols)

ReDim arr_in(idx_init To n_rows, idx_init To n_cols)
ReDim arr_out(idx_init To n_rows, idx_init To n_cols)

arr_in = rng.Value
r_pointer = 0
For r = n_rows To idx_init Step -1
  ' Adapt to case comparison mode required.
  If arr_in(r, c_target) <> x_cmp Then
    r_pointer = r_pointer + 1
    For c = idx_init To n_cols
      arr_out(r_pointer, c) = arr_in(r, c)
    Next c
  End If
Next r
rng.Value = arr_out

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Your code took `1.58 sec`.

Your code with `ScreenUpdating` and automatic calculation off took `1.63 sec`.

My code took `0.46 sec`.

Comment: Yes using Array approach is much faster.

Comment: Please, could you code golf your macro? and also add some additional comments ?

Comment: The main part of the code that does main job takes about 15 lines. At the moment, I don't know how to make it shorter. Also, why do you want it shorter?