# VBA "Object Required" Error (424) when trying to manipulate/delete filtered rows in vba macro

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I am writing a macro with the aim of importing data and generate a cleaned up table.

After importing, I form a table and try to filter and remove irrelevant rows. and naturally filter back to the only one item I want - `"Logged"` here.

The filter works up to the following line:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
        Criteria1:=Array("Cancelled", "Done", "On Hold", "PreReg")
```

Which properly filters what I want. I can view it when I run it in step-wise format and it works. When I try to delete is where things get interesting and not working.

I tried to use `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete`, `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`, and `Select` and then `with selection` doing the same functions. Almost all of them give back Run-time Error 424: Object Required.

I have looked up solutions below:
1- From [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17194394/vba-how-to-delete-filtered-rows-in-excel)  multiple posts were using the same solution - specialcells - and as you see it did not work.
2- From the same link as 1, a response offered the following:

```
ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1,0).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Delete(xlShiftUp)
```

While this solution works, I am trying to use the table as an object and then filter. As [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) documentation indicates, the output for either cases should be a variant and it seems that applying even `.rows` in the following manner gives the same error 424:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
        Criteria1:=Array("Cancelled", "Done", "On Hold", "PreReg").Rows
```

3- I got suspicious of whether I use names for objects wrong. So I went to the basics and recorded a macro that made the following lines for me:

```
    Table4.Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, _
     Criteria1:=Array("Cancelled", "Done", "On Hold", "PreReg"), Operator _
     :=xlFilterValues
    Range("Table4").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete ' **** This line does not seem right!!!
    Table4.Range.AutoFilter Field:=10
```

The challenge this time is repeatability and hidden rows. After running it multiple rounds, I got the two issues:
Issue 1: One or more rows get stuck and hidden. As such, in a very unusual way, even if I hold the code `Stop` and F8 through, it does not allow me to filter back or even show `"Logged"` - the one I want to keep!
Issue 2: Some times it completely deletes the data leaving the table empty! I pasted the data in row 2 and below to keep 1 row blank up top and this issue essentially leaves me with only headers in row 2, hides row 3, and the rest of the excel sheet is blank.

Would you be able to help and point out what am I missing?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` returns a non-continuous range, `EntireRow.Delete` raises runtime error 1004.
- The return value of `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` maybe is empty, adding `If` before delete rows is necessary.
- Removing the desired rows after `ShowAllData` is a good option.

```vb
With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4")
    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
        Criteria1:=Array("Cancelled", "Done", "On Hold", "PreReg")
    Dim visRng As Range
    Set visRng = .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
        .AutoFilter.ShowAllData
        visRng.Delete
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked for my application. The check for emptiness of rows was missing. Solution by @Attila has the `.ShowAllData` after. I checked that and it worked too. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```vb
Sub main()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table4").Range
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    r.AutoFilter Field:=10, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:=Array("Cancelled", "Done", "On Hold", "PreReg")
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(10).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 1 > 0 Then _
        r.Offset(1, 0).Resize(r.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

1. You set a range which will be your table's data.
2. Turn off DisplayAlerts - if not then you receive 'Are you sure you want to delete...?' popups. You are sure.
3. Apply your filter on the range based on your original post
4. If the visible rows count is higher than 0 then extend the range by using  offset - 1 row down (header), 0 columns to last visible row and column.
5. Delete rows by calling Rows.Delete on this range set by Offset
6. Turn DisplayAlerts back on
7. Remove the filter